# Making a module fail on purpose when trying to import it

Tags: powershell, error-handling, module

Is there a canonical way to make a module fail when it is tried to be imported with `import-module`, for example because a specific precondition is not met.

Currently, I have the following three lines at the start of the module:

```
if ( [IntPtr]::Size -ne 4 ) {
    throw '32 bit environment required' 
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better (or more agreed upon way) to prevent using a module in a 64-bit environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a better (or more agreed upon way) to prevent using a module in a 64-bit environment.

PowerShell's [Module Manifest schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest) has a configuration element for just this - `ProcessorArchitecture`!

```
New-ModuleManifest -Path My32BitOnlyModule.psd1 -ProcessorArchitecture x86
```

Or, if you need to add to an existing module manifest:

```
@{
  # ...
  ProcessorArchitecture = 'x86'
  # ...
}
```

For 64-bit architectures, the label is `Amd64`

Comment: This is a great feature. If I had a very specific application-domain related precondition, would I have to still go with `throw`?

Comment: `throw` from inside a `.psm1` at import-time seems an entirely reasonable stopgap to me, yes! :-)